# jQuery Validation plugin and ajax form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a simple multipart/form-data form submitted with ajax after validation using jQuery Validation Plugin.

I disable the submit button before submit and after successful form submission enable the submit button and reset all the form fields. The form code is working on Chromium Browser on a Debian Box.

Is there a better/cleaner way of doing this?

```
<form class="aForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
File To Upload: <input class="aData" type="file" name="aData" /><br/>
Name of User: <input type="text" name="aName" class="aName" placeholder="Name" 
/><br/>
Date: <input type="text" name="aDate" class="aDate" placeholder="Date" /></br/>
<input type="hidden" value="5f25c045bf33ac72fcf5f8bc23b4c862d220d385" name="csrfToken" >

<button class="aButton">Button</button>
</form>
```

---

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".aForm").validate({
    rules: {
      aData: {
        required: true,
        extension: "png|jpg",
      },
      aName: "required",
      aDate: "required"
    },
    messages: {
      aData: "No Data",
      aName: "No Name",
      aDate: "No Date"
    },
    submitHandler: function(){
      $('.aButton').prop('disabled', true);
      var formData = new FormData($('.aForm')[0]);
      console.log(formData);
      $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success:
          function(data){
            alert(data);
            $('.aForm')[0].reset();
            $('.aButton').prop('disabled', false);
          },
        error: 
        function(jqXHR, textStatus){
          console.log(textStatus);
        }

      });
}
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Above block of codes are working in live production without any problem. Tested on IE9 to IE 11, Chrome on windows and Linux. There are no Firefox users.